# CakePHP validation, error messages in Auth and disabling modified.

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have tried to get this function working in the desired way but not having much luck.
The good news is, is that it works.  Only thing I wanted to get working correctly is the field validation error messages which I managed to, but could not login in even if the username and password were correct.  I have rolled back the function in the hope that someone could shed some light on this for me please.

```
    function login() {
            $this->layout = 'login';
            $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Login');
            if (!empty($this->data) && $id = $this->Auth->user('id')) { 
                    $this->User->id = $id; 
                    $this->User->saveField('last_login', date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); 
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('You have successfully logged in', true));
                    $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index')); 
            }    
    }
```

The validation which I have setup in the users model:

```
var $validate = array(
                'username' => array(
               ),
                'login' => array(
                            'rule' => 'isUnique',
                            'message' => 'This username has already been taken',
                     ),
                    'pattern' => array(
                            'rule' => array('custom','/[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]{6,}$/i'),
                            'message' => 'Must be 6 characters or longer with no spaces',
                    ),
                    'length' => array(
                            'rule' => array('maxLength', 15),
                            'message' => 'Please keep username under 15 characters',
                    ),
                    'notempty' => array(
                            'rule' => array('notempty'),
                            'message' => 'Username cannot be empty',
                    ),
            ),
        'password' => array(
                        'notempty' => array(
                                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                                'message' => 'Password cannot be empty',
                        ),
                        'length' => array(
                                'rule' => array('between', 5, 15),
                                'message' => 'Passwords must be between 5 and 15 characters long with no spaces',
                                'on' => 'create',
                        )
        )
);
```

I shall unset certain validation rules for the login, I for now would just like to get the validation actually working in the correct manner.

Really, I have three questions...

1. Why is my validation not working correctly?
2. How can I display messages from the `AuthComponent` in my views?
3. How can I temporarily disable the `modified` field in my table from updating?

Many thanks!

Comment: Here: `&& $id = $this->Auth->user('id')` in your if.  Is that a typo?  Should be `==` or `===`.

Comment: why do you need to validate at login to begin with??

Comment: @anh It's more so for the aesthetics than actual functional aspect - I suppose I could live with the session flashing ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the error I found in my comment I'm fairly certain your `login` validation isn't setup correctly.

Here's what you have:

```
'login' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'This username has already been taken',
            ),
                        'pattern' => array(
                                'rule' => array('custom','/[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]{6,}$/i'),
                                'message' => 'Must be 6 characters or longer with no spaces',
                        ),
                        'length' => array(
                                'rule' => array('maxLength', 15),
                                'message' => 'Please keep username under 15 characters',
                        ),
                        'notempty' => array(
                                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                                'message' => 'Username cannot be empty',
                        ),
        ),
```

Here's what I **think** you want to have

```
'username' => array(
    'isUnique' => array(
        'rule' => 'isUnique',
        'message' => 'This username has already been taken'
    ),
    'pattern' => array(
        'rule' => array('custom','/[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]{6,}$/i'),
        'message' => 'Must be 6 characters or longer with no spaces',
    ),
    'length' => array(
        'rule' => array('maxLength', 15),
        'message' => 'Please keep username under 15 characters',
    ),
    'notEmpty' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'Username cannot be empty',
    ),
),
```

Mandatory links to the [CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/) and the [CakePHP API](http://api13.cakephp.org/).

---

Answer to error from OP in comment:

I see now what you were trying to do.  Try this:

```
$id = $this->Auth->user('id');
if (!empty($this->data) && $id) { 
                $this->User->id = $id;
```

---

Answer to "How to display my login error message from the `AuthComponent`?"

For the login error message to appear you will need to add the following line in your layout or view for your login form.

```
echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
```

---

Answer to "How to temporarily disable CakePHP's `modified` behavior?":

Well, a brief look at the source code and the [answer to this question on Cake's internal QA](http://ask.cakephp.org/questions/view/temporarily_disable_modified_automagic) you can add something like this before you save the data.

```
$this->data['User']['modified'] = false;
```

This tells Cake to not update the modified field.

*Interestingly enough from the source code it appears that you could just as easily replace `false` with `true` and it wouldn't update the field.  I don't know if this is actually the case though.*

Comment: changing if (!empty($this->data) && $id = $this->Auth->user('id')) to if (!empty($this->data) && $id == $this->Auth->user('id')) throws the following error:    Notice (8): Undefined variable: id [APP/controllers/users_controller.php, line 81]
Notice (8): Undefined variable: id [APP/controllers/users_controller.php, line 82]

Comment: Many thanks!  that sorted that out, however,  the validation error messages are still not showing..

Comment: Always something simple which is overlooked.. Thanks! The session flash messages are working again!  There is one curious thing happening.  $this->User->saveField('last_login', date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); is writing to both the [modified] and [last_login] fields and I am not sure why.

Comment: Well, the `modified` field being updated is [actually a feature.](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1015/created-and-modified).  You see, when you update `last_login` you're **modifying** that row, thus Cake's built in functionality kicks in and updates the `modified` field as well.  You aren't technically writing to both fields in your query, it just appears that way as the times may be similar.

Comment: You are a scholar and a gentleman. I cannot thank you enough for your help!  Is there no way to override this so it's only limited to the edit function?

Comment: Thanks for updating the post - apologies for all the questions!!  I have made attempts to add `$this->data['User']['modified'] = false;` to the login function, set to both true and false - and the field is still being updated regardless.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure.  Instead of trying to pile even more into this question I suggest you write up a new one explaining your problem with `modified` updating.  I've already crammed a lot into my answer and would rather not have a bunch of wide-ranging stuff.  It makes it more difficult for other people to find good information.

Comment: Yep, no worries - this one is starting to cover far to much!  Your help has been greatly appreciated!